# Descriminating between text and binary websocket messages in the browser

Tags: javascript, websocket, blob

The following code snippet receives websocket messages.  It tries to `readAsText` the blob and also display it as a JPEG.

```
      ws.onmessage = function(message) {
        console.log('websocket blob:', message.data);
        var text = reader.readAsText(message.data);
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(message.data);
        console.log("jpeg received");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      }
    }
    reader.onload = function(progressEvent) {
      var text = this.result;
      if (text.startsWith('{"')) {
        console.log("status received", text);
        document.querySelectorAll('pre')[0].textContent=text;
      }
    }
```

(The code is broken as it is trying to display plain text messages as JPEGs.)

How can I discriminate between two different sorts of incoming websocket packets?  I am in control of both ends, so I can change what the NodeJS server sends, if required.

My JSON packets always begin with `{"` and my JPEG packets always begin with `FF D8 FF`.

Is there a way of attaching some meta-data to the websocket messages, when sending, that I could query in the page?

Can I do any processing of websocket blobs without callback methods?

Comment: Why not set your websocket to use arraybuffers then encode both your jpegs and json into it? You could set the first byte to an id to distinguish between whether you're decoding into a JSON string or a jpeg

Comment: @Rhys Thanks, I've just found out about `socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';`...

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is now:

```
    ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
    ...

      ws.onmessage = function(message) { // FIXME: utf8-unsafe
        var arrayView = new Uint8Array(message.data);
        console.log('websocket message:', arrayView);
        if (arrayView[0] === 0xFF) { // jpeg
          console.log("jpeg received");
          var blob = new Blob([arrayView], {type: "image/jpeg"});
          img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        } else { // text
          console.log("text received");
          document.querySelectorAll('pre')[0].textContent=String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arrayView);
        }
      }
```

I would prefer a UTF8 safe handler, but that can wait until other parts of the project are working.